# Drawing circle on Matlab GUI window, not on the axis

Tags: matlab, user-interface, geometry, figure

I have a GUI that has an axis and some buttons on it. I could draw a little filled circle in a critical point of the axis by using rectangle command. Now I want to show the user what this point means. I mean, I want to put a circle 'outside the axes' and put a little explanation. However I could only display it on the axis.

This is what I want graphically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTMnB.jpg

How can I solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use pixels as unit, you can use `annotation` to draw at position (200,150) a circle of radius 10, in the figure having the handle `hf`:

```
annotation(hf, 'ellipse', [200 150 10 10], 'EdgeColor', 'r', 'FaceColor', 'r')
```

Comment: @UgurParlatan Glad that I could help.